# Nginx + gunicorn show 502 randomly

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, nginx, gunicorn

My system has an issue recently, it worked fine before without any issues.

From Nginx error log, I see there is a lot of error:

```
connect() to unix:/home/ubuntu/site/site.sock failed (11: Resource 
temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 
10.0.14.213, server: www.example.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico 
HTTP/1.1", upstream: 
"http://unix:/home/ubuntu/site/site.sock:/favicon.ico", host: 
"www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/tin-tuc/"
```

These errors are from many randomly requests, not all requests. I still able to access the website, but sometimes get 502 bad request.

It uses 2 VPS for web application. Each one has Nginx working as proxy pass to web application (Python + Django) using Socket.

This is Nginx config (/etc/nginx/nginx.conf):

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 100480;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        server_tokens off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECD$

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        client_body_buffer_size 100k;
        client_header_buffer_size 100k;
        client_max_body_size 10M;
        large_client_header_buffers 4 100k;
        add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;";
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
 }
```

Nginx site config (/etc/nginx/sites-available/default):

```
server {
     listen 80 default_server;
     listen [::]:80 default_server;
root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

location /nginx_status {
            # Turn on stats
            stub_status on;
            access_log   off;
            # only allow access from 192.168.1.5 #
            #allow 192.168.1.5;
            #deny all;
       }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    client_body_timeout 10;
    client_header_timeout 10;
    keepalive_timeout 5 5;
    send_timeout 10;
    if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|PUT|POST|PATCH|DELETE|HEAD)$ ) {
            return 444;
    }

    location /media {
            access_log off;
            alias /home/ubuntu/site/media;
            expires 30d;
    }

    location /static {
            access_log off;
            alias /home/ubuntu/site/public;
            expires 30d;
    }
    location ~ ^/(apple-app-site-association|\.well-known/apple-app-site-association) {
            access_log off;
            alias /home/ubuntu/meddy/meddy_site/static/apple-app-site-association ;
            expires 30d;
            default_type application/pkcs7-mime;
    }

    location / {
            if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = http) {
                    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
            }
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/meddy/meddy_site/meddy_site.sock;
            #proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        # setting equivalent to WSGIPASSAUTHORIZATION on in Apache(mod_wsgi)
            proxy_pass_request_headers on;
            proxy_no_cache $cookie_nocache  $arg_nocache$arg_comment;
            proxy_no_cache $http_pragma     $http_authorization;
            proxy_cache_bypass $cookie_nocache $arg_nocache $arg_comment;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_pragma $http_authorization;
            proxy_connect_timeout 3600;
            proxy_send_timeout 3600;
            proxy_read_timeout 3600;
    }
}
```

Here is my supervisor config:

```
source /home/ubuntu/env/bin/activate
cd /home/ubuntu/site

export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=site.settings.production
exec gunicorn --workers 4 --timeout 90 \
    --error-logfile /home/ubuntu/error.log \
    --log-level=error \
    --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/site/site.sock \
    site.wsgi:application
```

Each web application server has 2 cores CPU, 4G Ram. CPU usage around 30%, Ram 50%.

By default somaxconn value is 128 and everything still works fine before. When the issue happens, I have tried to set it to 1000 but it still throws 502 error, and the website becomes slower.

I also enable gunicorn error log and no error found from the application.

The application uses Elastic Search and I'm new with this database so I don't know if there is any issue with it.

Comment: it seems nginx has problem to connect to gunicorn. maybe you should change `log-level` to get more information. OR maybe gunicorn is too busy to response for request so you needs more workers and longer timeout ?

Comment: using Google `"gunicorn 502 bad request"` I found article [NGINX 502 Bad Gateway: Gunicorn](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/nginx-502-bad-gateway-errors-gunicorn/) and there is more links - ie. to forums.

Comment: @furas: can you tell me log-level of what? How could I know if gunicorn too busy? Following to the link you sent, I have set the timeout for nginx and gunicorn but it still happens. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: What are the average load times for the pages that are getting 502s? 502 can sometimes be caused by the upstream (django) not responding in time

Comment: @IainShelvington It happens immediately, very quick. Not the case which we have to wait for a long time then it returns 502.

Comment: when you start gunicorn then there is option `--log-level`. You could create script which uses linux command  `ps aux`  to check if gunicorn is on list of running processes (You can use module `subprocess` or module `psutils` should function to get this in easy way). But supervisor controls if program works and automatically restarts it so it may be problem to catch moment when gunicorn doesn't work. If supervisor starts gunicorn again then it may have different process ID - `pid.